# Cursor is not place at end of custom element

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable

```css
p code {
  padding: 1px 5px 1px 5px;
}
code {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  padding: 1px 5px;
  font-family: Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Courier New, monospace, sans-serif;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false" style="height: 350px;"><p>efiwefwpei&nbsp;<code>fowef</code>&nbsp;wefwefwefwefweff</p></div>
```

1. Why cursor is not place at ending of `code` element when i want to continuos typing
2. I want to typing at beginning of `code` element, It can't do it

How to fix that (in the way of good user experience and `code` element it look like that)